# grep specific string from a file and store the result in another file using bat or vbs

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have the below contents in file1

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\vlc.exe\shell\Open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe\" --started-from-file \"%1\""
```

I need `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe` string to be copied from file1 to file2.

As a end result file2 contents should have

```
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe
```

How can we achieve this using a bat file or a vbs ? Please share your thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. You might get the best response if you show what you've tried already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a IN (q21568377.txt) DO IF NOT "%%b"=="" FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=:-" %%c IN (%%b) DO SET var1=%%c&SET var2=%%d
SET var=%var1:~-1%:%var2:~0,-3%
ECHO %var%

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q21568377.txt` for my testing.

Output simply shown on screen. Redirect to file if that's your wish.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
for /f usebackq^ tokens^=^3^ delims^=^" %%a in ("file1") do >"file2" echo %%a
```

Using the quote as delimiter, read file1, split the lines to get the third token in line and send to file2